# how to launch my own admob app on real phone

Tags: android, admob, firebase-admob

After displaying Admob(banner, full screen ad) and releasing the app, I know that my account will be suspended if I launched my app using my cellphone.

What should I do if I want to run my app on my phone when I'm outside?(when my body is totally physically outside which is when I can`t use computer/Emulator-test ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use .addTestDevice("Your Test Device Id") parameter in the Ad Request Builder method.

Test Device ID should look like ("FB9F1C3D53382E1666489F5407301E91") you should obtain it from logcat

Then instead of using released app, you should use debugged version of the app builded by your Android Studio.(I mean do not download your own app for usage. Simply directly build it from Android studio) Then you should see a "Test Ad" attribution on your ads. It is safe to use like this

Comment: is there no way to do this? I mean I can\`t stay all day in front of a PC when I`m outside, I want to use my phone for this and I want to see

Comment: You can, just add your mobile device as test device yo your ads

Comment: If I do so, am I not supposed to be suspend?(account suspend)